# PM2 doesn't start the node process after reboot

Tags: centos, pm2

I'm trying to automatically start a process after rebooting. But it doesn't start. I see message like this:

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/my_user/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem │ user │ watching │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

My steps:

`npm install -g pm2` - install pm2 globaly on my centOS vps as root.

`pm2 startup systemd -u my_user —-hp /home/my_user` - add pm2 to startup

`su my_user` - switch user

`pm2 start --name myProcess app.js` - start the process with name "myProcess"

`pm2 save` - save the current process list.

Earlier it used to work.
What I'm doing wrong now?

Comment: You should consider using `systemctl --user` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User . I transformed from using PM2 to Systemd

Comment: I recommend to move this question to serverfault

Answer (score 0):

@Nastro please create a run.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh

yarn
yarn start
```

`pm2 start run.sh` and to run in cluster write command `pm2 start run.sh -i max`

This works fine!